# Ubuntu Install ISO uses 'extend monitors' at the beginning

Tags: system-installation, multiple-monitors, iso

I am trying to install Ubuntu on a laptop with no monitor.

Yes, it means it does not have a monitor, it wasn't working, so I removed it.

Even though I can see the Ubuntu Boot logs on the external monitor, as soon as it boots up, it only shows the external monitor as a second monitor extended to internal monitor.

Even the right click option does not work.

I believe what is showing on the missing internal monitor is Ubuntu graphical menu option.

Is there any shortcut or a way so that I can see these options (or change extend monitors to mirror monitors)?

To clarify more, I can see the Ubuntu background on the external monitor, and I can see the cursor. But Ubuntu Install ISO at this stage, does not even accept a right-click option, and therefore it is also not accepting any keyboard commands, before 'Try Ubuntu' is selected (which could be called as a bug maybe, whatever it is, it is not convenient). It means I cannot open a terminal by keyboard shortcuts, and also Fn+F8 or any other change monitor key is not accepted.

P.S.: If somebody knows how to make suggestions to Ubuntu, you can tell or write them that; on the install ISO, using 'extend multiple monitors' option at the beginning is a terrible idea, especially when the user is just limited to selecting an option on a graphical menu.

UPDATE: I just cut the connection between monitor and motherboard, and BIOS does not see internal monitor anymore, but Ubuntu Install ISO still does. Therefore, it is a bug in official distributed Ubuntu Install ISO.

Comment: Many notebooks will let you use keyboard shortcuts to change the behaviour of the video output, allowing you to toggle between extend, mirror, and external only. Does your half-notebook have this feature?

Comment: It does, but neither that button nor right-click or anything else works, because the install ISO is just presenting a graphical option to choose to try or install. So, no shortcuts, commands, or keyboard actions work at this stage. It means at that point, even though computer is booted, I cannot go ahead and start a terminal with keyboard shortcuts, because 'Try Ubuntu' is not activated yet.

Comment: My laptops have a key combo using the laptop's Fn key, for example, my Dell I can use Fn+F8 key to switch through mirror, extend etc.  I have been able to boot Ubuntu install using this method before.